# How to reset Eclipse Luna theme to "none"

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, themes, eclipse-luna

after installing luna I had no theme set which resulted in following UI:

[image]

Needless to say, I really like that look. :)
When playing with some settings i changed the UI theme and now I can't get back.
The combo box where u can set your theme doesn't allow empty selection.

[image]

Now I am stuck with the old theme.
Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting my current workspace settings revealed entries containing following String:

```
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_default6.1
```

Apparently it is the native name of the "Windows 7 classic" Theme in eclipse.
Searching my workspaces .metadata folder revealed 12 occurences (I recommend EditPlus or Notepad++ for this).
After deleting those I got my clean "null" theme look.

Now I am happy again. :)